# File './binlog.000007' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql, debian

I have this error when running mysql

```
mysqld: File './binlog.000007' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
2019-06-10T01:08:57.188811Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 2210
2019-06-10T01:08:57.871257Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010958] [Server] Could not open log file.
2019-06-10T01:08:57.871297Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010041] [Server] Can't init tc log
2019-06-10T01:08:57.873856Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-06-10T01:08:59.423691Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

In the same directory, you'll find `binlog.index` file.

windows: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.0\data\binlog.index`

Linux: `/var/lib/mysql/binlog.index`

Remove entry of `'./binlog.000007'` and restart the server..

Comment: OP doesn't really tell us how mysql is being ran, might even be in xamp and that would be different. I think this answer does not provide context.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say *where* you're running MySQL (inside Virtual Box, or a Docker image; Windows or Linux), but this should resolve the problem:

> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151183/mariadb-cant-init-tc-log
>
> Woohoo, I found it! For now, at least. Digging through the source
>   suggests that this might have something to do with mmap() calls, and
>   lo and behold - VirtualBox has a bug in that area. Fortunately that
>   same source hints at a workaround - the log_bin option. Enable this
>   (either from the command line as `--log_bin` or from the config file
>   as `log_bin=ON`) and things start to work again!

Comment: It seems to me that I accidentally deleted the binlog.000007 file

Comment: Dude - if you think you "accidentally deleted the file" ... then did you try *RESTARTING THE MYSQL*?  If the restart fixed the problem - great.  If it didn't ... do you *really* think mysql wouldn't recreate the file itself??? Would you at least *CONSIDER* trying `log_bin=ON` (or equivalent)?

Comment: Q: Have you found the problem?  Q: Did you try setting log_bin and restarting mysql?